# Altering a SQL 2000 table that is replicated

Tags: replication, sql-server

I have a database that is published, and a seperate server subscribes to this publication.
We are using Transactional Replication (as far as I can tell)

I need to alter a column on ServerA (the published database)
Will the changes be reflected on ServerB (the subscriber) or do I need to change it there too?

Do i need to re-initialize anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly SQL 2000 doesn't allow you to change columns.  You have to add a new column with the new size, then move the data, then drop the old column.

This can't be done with the normal ALTER TABLE command.  You have to use the replication stored procedures to add and remove the columns.

The least complex way to do it is to remove the replication, make the changes, then resetup replication.